# Método "sort" retornando apenas "None", qual o motivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou resolvendo um problema em Python 3, sobre listas.

Parte da minha solução envolve ordenar uma lista de valores `float`, resolvi usar o método [`sort`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp). Esse método deveria retornar a lista já ordenada, em ordem crescente, mas não é isso que está acontecendo.

A função que eu estou escrevendo funciona mais ou menos assim:

```
def inverter(lista):
    lista_invertida = []

    lista = lista.sort()
    lista_invertida = lista[::-1]

    return lista_invertida
```

---

No entanto isso não estava surtindo efeito, fiz um teste para verificar se havia algo "quebrado".

Escrevi um `print` para me mostrar a lista antes e depois de ser ordenada.

Antes de ser ordenada a lista era assim:

```
34.7, 43.5, 31.1, 40.7, 20.3, 19.9
```

Logo depois da ordenação a lista ficou assim:

```
None, None, None, None, None, None
```

Isso quebrou a função que eu tinha escrito, o interpretador ficou tentando inverter a lista só formada por `None`...

Gostaria de saber se existe algo de errado, e/ou se há uma forma de corrigir esse retorno.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O método `list.sort` modifica a **própria llista**, não retorna um novo objeto tal como ocorre com a função `sorted`. Desta forma, você está sobrescrevendo o objeto `lista` com o retorno de `list.sort`, que é `None`.

Para corrigir, ao invés de fazer:

```
lista = lista.sort()
```

Faça apenas

```
lista.sort()
```

Porém, se a ideia é inverter a lista depois, por que não ordena já de forma reversa?

```
lista.sort(reverse=True)
```

Assim não precisará fazer `lista[::-1]` para inverter a lista.

**MAS MUITO CUIDADO**

Uma vez utilizando `list.sort` dentro da função, a sua lista **fora da função** também será alterada. Se você quer que a lista permaneça inalterada ao chamar a função o ideal será utilizar a função `sorted`, que cria uma nova lista para fazer a ordenação:

```
def inverter(lista):
    return sorted(lista, reverse=True)
```

Por exemplo:

**Usando ordenação com `list.sort`**

```
>>> lista = [4, 5, 2, 6]
>>> print(inverter(lista))
[6, 5, 4, 2]
>>> print(lista)
[6, 5, 4, 2]
```

Perceba que `lista` também foi alterada.

**Usando ordenação com `sorted`**

```
>>> lista = [4, 5, 2, 6]
>>> print(inverter(lista))
[6, 5, 4, 2]
>>> print(lista)
[4, 5, 2, 6]
```

Perceba que `lista` não foi alterada após chamar a função.

Comment: Perfeito!!! O `sort(reverse = True)` resolveu, por ainda ter algumas coisas que preciso tratar.

Answer (score 3):

invés de usar lista = lista.sort()
use somente lista.sort()

Comment: Funciona, mas a resposta do @Anderson Carlos Woss, foi mais completa e ainda evitou um possível erro, alterando a lista de maneira global.