# Por que ao ordenar uma lista com sort(), retorna None?

Tags: python, classificação, dicionário

O script a seguir ordena um dicionário:

```
d = {'a': 10, 'g': 15, 'c': 67, 'z': 90, 'e': 144}

ordenada = list(d.keys()) # gera uma lista das chaves do dicionário (protegida por uma tupla)
ordenada.sort() # ordena a lista de chaves
for chave in ordenada:
    print(chave, '=', d[chave], end=', ') # mapeia os valores com as chaves ordenadas
```

Tentei desta forma também e não consegui:

```
ordenada = list(d.keys()).sort()
print(ordenada) # está retornando None
```

Queria entender porquê aplicando o método `sort()` na mesma linha ele está retornando `None`. Achei que o paradigma de orientação a objeto seria aplicado aqui, onde primeiro eu transformo `d.keys()` em um objeto `list` para em seguida coloca-lo em ordem. Faz sentido?
Aproveitando, se puderem, explicar o significado de None em algum outro caso mais elaborado.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Método "sort" retornando apenas "None", qual o motivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/375211/m%c3%a9todo-sort-retornando-apenas-none-qual-o-motivo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), `list.sort` altera a lista *in-place* (ou seja, os elementos da lista são rearranjados internamente, em vez de retornar outra lista). Lá também é dito que "*it does not return the sorted sequence*" (não retorna a lista ordenada).

Mais ainda, a documentação [também afirma que](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types):

> *The methods that add, subtract, or rearrange their members in place, and don’t return a specific item, never return the collection instance itself but `None`.*

Ou seja, métodos como `sort`, que alteram o conteúdo *in place* e não retornam a própria lista, retornam `None`.

---

Se quiser que retorne outra lista, use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
d = {'a': 10, 'g': 15, 'c': 67, 'z': 90, 'e': 144}
ordenada = sorted(d.keys())
for chave in ordenada:
    print(chave, '=', d[chave], end=', ')
```

Obs: o `for` acima imprime uma vírgula a mais no final, então uma forma de imprimir corretamente seria:

```
print(', '.join(f'{chave} = {d[chave]}' for chave in ordenada))
```

Que imprime:

```
a = 10, c = 67, e = 144, g = 15, z = 90
```