# Python: Diferenças ao imprimir Ordem Crescente e Decrescente

Tags: python-3.x

Porque ao imprimir o resultado de uma lista em ordem crescente o `print` aceita colocar a função `sorted()`? Diferente do `num.sort(reverse=True)`que tenho que instanciar antes?

**Exemplo:**

```
print(f'Sua lista de números em ordem crescente é: {sorted(num)}')
```

já em ordem decrescente, eu tenho que instanciar fora do `print`:

**Exemplo:**

```
num.sort(reverse=True)
print(f'Sua lista de números em ordem decrescente é: {num}')
```

**Queria fazer em apenas uma linha, como:**

```
print(f'Sua lista de números ao inverso é: {num.sort(reverse=True)}')
```

Aplicando dentro do `print` o meu foi: `None`

Quem puder me ajude a entender o porquê, trata-se apenas de uma dúvida de principiante.
Se tiverem uma maneira mais prática, aceito sugestões.

Abraços!

Comment: Além do que já foi explicado abaixo, vale lembrar que `sorted` não se restringe à listas, pois pode receber qualquer iterável (por exemplo, com tuplas, `set`'s, generators, etc), e retorna uma nova lista com os elementos ordenados (é diferente de `sort`, que é exclusivo de listas)

Comment: @hkotsubo Muito Obrigado! Me ajudou a entender! Maravilha! Abraços!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O sorted() não altera a lista, mas retorna os valores da lista ordenada. Já  sort() altera a lista diretamente na variável e não retorna nenhum valor, logo ele  organiza os valores e os sobrepõe dentro da lista anteriormente declarada, não retornando os valores ordenados, mas sim retornando literalmente nada (None)

Por exemplo:

```
lista = [5,4,2,3,1]
print("O valor ordenado é", sorted(lista))
print("A lista original é", lista)
```

Como saída disso, tem-se:

```
O valor ordenado é [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
A lista original é [5, 4, 2, 3, 1]
```

Como exemplificado, o sorted() não alterou a lista original, ele apenas retornou os valores organizados sem a necessidade da sobreposição dos valores ordenados.

Já o .sort(), sobrepõe os valores na lista original e retorna "nada" quando a função é chamada (None). Como por exemplo:

```
lista = [5,4,2,3,1]
print("O valor ordenado é", lista.sort())
print("A lista original é", lista)
```

Tem-se como saída:

```
O valor ordenado é None
A lista original é [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Como vemos no exemplo, a função .sort() retornou apenas "NONE" e organizou os valores originais. Então toda vez que o sort() estiver em um print, ele irá retornar apenas o valor "NONE", impossibilitando assim o uso do mesmo em mostrar a ordenação em uma função print.

Portanto, se houver a necessidade de imprimir os valores que foram ordenados pelo .sort(), deve-se utilizar o sort() primeiro e imprimir a variável original depois, levando em consideração que ela foi ordenada e os novos valores substituíram os valores originais, como:

```
lista = [5,4,2,3,1]
lista.sort()
print("O Valor ordenado é", lista)
```

Saída:

```
O Valor ordenado é [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: **Obrigado pela explicação.**

Mas minha dúvida também se refere o porquê do `[num.sort(reverse=True)]` não pode ser utilizado dentro da função [print], sendo possível apenas se declarar antes.

no caso:

`lista.sort(reverse=True)
print(f'Sua lista de números em ordem decrescente é: {lista}')`

Comment: @EvaldoOestreichFilho Porque `lista.sort()` retorna `None`. É um método que altera a própria lista, mas não a retorna, por isso não dá pra usar diretamente no `print`. Isso está explicado aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/375211/112052